# bash - use a variable int value to refer to position parameter in a function

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I would like to use a variable say:

```
i=1
```

as a value to refer to positional variables passed to script, e.g.:

```
x=101
y=201
z=301

foo(){
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
    echo "$3"
}

foo x y z
```

output:

```
101
201
301
```

Instead of refering to each parameter by index, how could I use `i` to increment through as a index variable?

**To clarify:**

```
foo() {
    local i=1
    echo "$i" #echo first paramter
    (( i+=1 ))
    echo "$i" #echo second parameter
    #etc.
}
```

what is the syntax for the `echo "$i"` part?

UPDATE after @Eric answer

```
~$ t=5
~$ foo() { i=1; echo "${!i}"; }
~$ foo t
t
~$
```

**Update #2**

So in short, the only way I can make my method work is by this:

```
foo() { #assuming 3 parameters

    i=0
    (( i+=1 ))
    var="${!i}"
    echo "${!var}"

    (( i+=1 ))
    var="${!i}"
    echo "${!var}"

    (( i+=1 ))
    var="${!i}"
    echo "${!var}"        
}
```

Comment: Best to use *array*s. But if you'd like the form `${!i}` can be useful for you

Comment: Other way is to use `shift` command to operate arguments

Comment: Well, as the examples showed, you don't have to manually increment `i` yourself, but more or less.  What is it that you're really trying to accomplish though?  This feels like it could be a bit of an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497811/how-to-get-the-nth-positional-argument-in-bash), which is similar to @costas comment.  You can use `$#` to get the number of arguments and then [indirect references](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) like `${!i}` to access a variable by name.  Here's an example:

```
f() {
    for((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
        printf "%d %s\n" "$i" "${!i}"
    done
}

f a b c
```

which prints:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Seeing now that you want to pass in the names of variables as the positional arguments, you can an extra layer of indirect reference like so:

```
a=first
b=second
c=third

f() {
    for((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
        var="${!i}"
        printf "%d %s\n" "$i" "${!var}"
    done
}

f a b c
```

which prints

```
1 first
2 second
3 third
```

This lets us treat each argument as the name of a variable, which we store in `var` here.  Then we access that variable indirectly in the `printf`.

You only get one layer of indirection at a time, nesting doesn't work.  So trying to do it in one fell swoop as `${!${!i}}` doesn't work because the first `{` starts the expansion, with the rest being treated as the PARAMETER value to expand.  The first character being `!` it will treat the rest as the name of the PARAMETER containing the name of the parameter we want, but `${!i}` is not a valid parameter name, so we get a `bad substitution`.  So we just do it in 2 steps to avoid that problem.

Comment: see edit, this is does not seem to work for me

Comment: @Cybex See my update for the extra layer of indirection if you want to pass in the name of a variable to access

Comment: Thank you, this works, will mark as correct, however please explain the purpose of var="${!i}". When I tried combining the var and "print" variables from your edit, like this " echo "${!${!i}}"  ", it fails, with a bad substitution. Could you elaborate on the var used and how it is used to display the containing data.

Comment: See update #2 please

Answer (score 2):

Using `shift`, you can do the following:

```
num_args="$#"

for (( i = 1; i <= "$num_args"; i++ )); do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

Here, the `shift` command *shifts* every next argument from the arguments passed to the script to be the value of `$1`.

For example:

```
$ ./myscript one two three four five six
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

whereby, in first run of the loop, `$1 = "one"`, then in second run of loop, `$1 = "two"`, so forth, until last argument.

---

**Edit:** If you want access to any of your script arguments without order, eg. using 2nd and 4th arguments at the same time, one method is using bash arrays as follows:

```
# Initialize the array 'myargs' with all script arguments
myargs=( "$@" )

for (( i = 0; i < "$#"; i++ )); do
    echo "${myargs[$i]}"
done
```

Here, you can access any of your arguments with any specified index `i` using the form `"${myargs[$i]}"`.

Comment: how would I retrieve variable #2 (or any other processed variable) when I shifted to current variable #4 ( or higher )?

Comment: Unfortunately, when you shift, your initial `$1` values get lost unless you store them in another variable. Hence, the edit I made above, using an array to access any and all arguments freely any time in the script.